# Link all query (select and delete) in one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make one statement(automated) of the following queries.

All i know proposal id from my UI. i do query manually like below

```
select * from tblAssessment where ProposalID like '%0081/2013/0587B%'

select * from tblAssessmentVersion where AssessmentID=587

select * from tblIdentifiedThreatenedSpecies where AssessmentVersionID=731

delete from tblIdentifiedThreatenedSpecies where PercentGain=0 and AssessmentVersionID=731
```

once i know the proposal id ,i query in to tblassessment to get the assessment id then use the assessment id to query in to assessmentversion table to find the assessment version ID then use the assessment version id in to Identified species table to delete the record where percentgain column is 0.

Appreciate all your help,thanks in advance

Comment: Use join to get the matching record in temp table or variable and then use that in delete query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DELETE FROM .. JOIN`:

```
DELETE s
FROM tblIdentifiedThreatenedSpecies s
INNER JOIN tblAssessmentVersion v
    ON v.AssessmentVersionID = s.AssessmentVersionID
INNER JOIN tblAssessment a
    ON a.AssessmentID = v.AssessmentID
WHERE
    a.ProposalID LIKE '%0081/2013/0587B%'
    AND PercentGain = 0
```

---

To check for rows to be deleted, `SELECT` first:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM tblIdentifiedThreatenedSpecies s
INNER JOIN tblAssessmentVersion v
    ON v.AssessmentVersionID = s.AssessmentVersionID
INNER JOIN tblAssessment a
    ON a.AssessmentID = v.AssessmentID
WHERE
    a.ProposalID LIKE '%0081/2013/0587B%'
    AND PercentGain = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

join all your SELECT in one subquery

```
delete from tblIdentifiedThreatenedSpecies 
where PercentGain=0 and AssessmentVersionID in
(
  select av.Id 
  from 
  tblAssessmentVersion av 
  join tblAssessment a on a.Id = av.AssessmentID
  where a.ProposalID like '%0081/2013/0587B%'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work.

```
delete from tblIdentifiedThreatenedSpecies 
where PercentGain=0 and AssessmentVersionID=(
   select top 1 AssessmentVersionID from tblAssessmentVersion where AssessmentID=(
      select top 1 AssessmentID from tblAssessment where ProposalID like '%0081/2013/0587B%'
   )
);
```

Here `top 1` is used if query returns more than one records, which is optional it your query doesn't.

Thank you.